# Time to completion

Tags: probability, expected-value

Say a person needs to go from A to B and also needs to complete a task. He may complete the task at either A or B. The task, say, takes 10 minutes. It takes 60 minutes to go from A to B after boarding the bus. The bus comes once an hour. When it will come is completely unknown to the man (so he may view the arrival of the bus as being uniformly distributed over the hour). My question is if his expected time of completion of the task and being in location B depends on if he immediately does the task before he goes out to wait for the bus or if he immediately goes out to wait for the bus and then does the task upon arrival to location B. This is not obvious to me.

Comment: Could he be doing the task at *A* and also be watching for the bus?  If so, and if he can abandon the task when the bus arrives and then start it all over again when he reaches *B*, that would shorten the expected duration.

Comment: Good point - I should have made that clear. He cannot do it while waiting for the bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the time start at time 0. Let's say that the bus arrives at time T minutes. Then T is uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 60]. Let X be the total time elapsed for the guy (including the task and travel).

In the first case, where the man does the task first (and risks missing the bus), the man's total time elapsed is in two cases:

```
Case A: If bus arrives in first 10 minutes and he misses it 
X = T + 60 + 60 = T + 120

Case B: If bus arrives after the first 10 minutes and he catches it 
X = T + 60
```

By the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),

```
E(X) = E(X | Case A) P(Case A) + E(X | Case B) P(Case B)
     = E(T + 120) 10/60 + E(T + 60) 50/60
     = 150 * 10/60 + 90 * 50/60
     = 100
```

Now, using the other strategy, the calculation is simpler. The man will definitely catch the bus in the first hour.

```
X = T + 60 + 10 = T + 70

E(X) = E(T + 60) = 100
```

So the *second strategy is equal in expectation to the first strategy*.

Let's think about this in an intuitive way. With the first strategy, the man will save 10 minutes 5 times out of 6 compared to the second strategy. He will lose 50 minutes 1 time out of 6 (because he will have already done the task). So on average, the 10 minutes he saves 5 times will balance the 50 minutes he loses 1 time.

Comment: +1 But there's a much simpler rationale: the total time is the sum of three variables, of which only one is random: doing the task, waiting for the bus, traveling.  The expectation doesn't care about what order the variables are summed, *QED*.